# How to configure nginx rules so that if one failed it serve the request using another

Tags: nginx

Note, this question is moved to stackoverflow from [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/642780/how-to-configure-nginx-rules-so-that-if-one-failed-it-serve-the-request-using-an)

I got the following nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...

    # specific rule to serve versioned js resources
    location ~ ^/js/([0-9\.]+)/(.*)$ {
      alias /opt/x/public/deploy/js/$1/$2;
    }

    location / {
        add_header P3P 'CP="CAO PSA OUR"';
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088;
        set $ssl off;
        if ($scheme = https) {
            set $ssl on;
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $ssl;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

It works as expected. However if a certain versioned js resource does not exists in the deployed dir, say `/opt/x/public/deployed/js/1.1/`, it will return `404`. What I want is in that case nginx shall pass the request to the backend service running at `8088` port instead of returning `404`. Is this even doable?

Thanks!
Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

try_files is your friend, here you can do the order you want to try files and finaly have the proxypass upstream.